# Amazon MSK Clutser updating broker max.connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

i need to codify the updating the of the `listener.name.client_iam.max.connections` for the kafka brokers which are hosted in a AWS MSK Cluster.
Reading this [material](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/limits.html) it looks like i have to use Kafka AlterConfig API or the kafka-configs.sh tool.
Does anyone have any examples of this either using Cloudformation or kubernetes.
I have tried using https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui this gives me the ability to update `listener.name.client_iam.max.connections` via the gui, but i need to remove the manual step..Many Thanks